# Solve for n in a formula

Tags: probability

This is a Chernoff bound especially for the cumulative distribution function of the binomial distribution:

$F(k; n,p) \leq \exp(-\frac{1}{2np}(np-k)^2)$

Can someone in the inequality

$-\frac{1}{2np}(np-k)^2 < \ln(\delta)$

solve for n?

thanks
D.

Comment: Multiply through by $2np$, expand, and move everything to the left side of the inequality. You get a quadratic inequality in $n$, which you should be able to solve from there. (If you can't, graphing it should help.)

Comment: Thanks can u be a lttle more specific?

Comment: Do you know how to solve $ax^2+bx+c<0$?

Comment: I mean with the expansion first.

Comment: Expand $(np-k)^2$ by performing the multiplication, using the distributive law.

Comment: $(np)^2+k^2-2knp/-2np<ln(\delta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to express the upper bound of the CDF in terms of n? What is the application. I worked the quadratic and got the following: $$n\geq \frac{\left((k - ln(\delta)) + \sqrt{(ln(\delta))^2 - 2kln(\delta)}\right)}{p}$$

I really do not how you are going to use this.

Thanks

Satish

Comment: In mathematica I get the opposite   $n \geq \frac{k-\ln(\delta)+\sqrt{\ln(\delta)\ln(\delta)-2k\ln(\delta)}}{p}$ \n I have to add $0<\delta<1$, $0<p<1$ and $k>0$

Comment: That is because your initial inequality is wrong, see the comment that I posted with the other responder.  It will be less than bigger root and greater than the smaller root.

Comment: Satish, u mean this inequality $-\frac{1}{2np}(np-k)^2 < \ln(\delta)$ is wrong? By doing calculations n should be equal to or  greater than the formula with the plus root. Actually it works also if n is equal to or less than the inequality with the minus sign, but not in between.

Comment: By Chernoff's inequality, you get the upper bound of the CDF.  Let us call this CDF $\delta$.  Then $\delta \leq \exp(-\frac{1}{2np}(np-k)^2)$.  Taking log on both sides you get $ln(\delta)\leq (-\frac{1}{2np}(np-k)^2)$  Now compare this with your it is the opporsite and hence the bounds of n should have the upper limit and lower limit which are roots of quadratic equation

Comment: Satish this $\delta$ is the probability of failure (say 0.1) which bounds from above the Chernoff bound. For example, I need 4 successes. How many trials should I do in order to ensure this number of successes given a specified error and a degree of certainty $(1-\delta)$.

Comment: You are right.  You  call the bound to be $\delta$ in which case it right, I was under the impression that you are defining F(n,k,p) to be $\delta$ and deriving the next inequality based on that. I am sorry for the confusion in which case direction and the limits of n are correct and please go ahead with your solution  and accept my apologies.